# Angular component.ts file

Tags: asp.net, angular

In my application, I have a list of categories.

When I click on `Edit` button, I'll be getting the data(name and urlHandle) of a single category based on it's id, from the api and these data will be displayed on Edit-Category component/page.

**The problem:**

*edit-category.components.ts file*

Here, I'm declaring an undefined variable (line 16) `category` which has the properties of `Category` model. But I'm getting error here `this.category=response;`

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { CategoryService } from '../services/category.service';
import { Category } from '../models/category.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-category',
  templateUrl: './edit-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-category.component.css']
})
export class EditCategoryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  id: string | null=null;
  paramSubscription?: Subscription;
  category?: Category;

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private categoryService: CategoryService){}
 

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.paramSubscription =  this.route.paramMap.subscribe({
      next:(params)=>{
        this.id=params.get('id');

        
        if(this.id){
          //get the data from API for this category id
          this.categoryService.getCategoryById(this.id)
          .subscribe({
            next:(response)=>{
              this.category=response;
            }
          });
      
         }
      }
    })

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.paramSubscription?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The error message is: `Type 'Category[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Category': id, name, urlHandle`

*model.ts file*

```
 export interface Category{
  id:string;
  name:string;
  urlHandle:string;
}
```

I thought  since `Category` is an array of properties(i.e id, name and urlhandle), it's expecting us to declare the variable category as an array like this -> `category?: Category[];`
But I was wrong. This lead to an error in html file

```
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="mt-3">Edit Category</h1>

  <ng-container *ngIf="category; else notFound">
    <form>
      <div class="mt-2">
        <div class="mt-3">
          <label for="categoryId">Category Id</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            disabled
            id="categoryId"
            class="form-control"
            name="categoryId"
            value="{{ category.id }}" //error in this line: property 'id' does not exist on type 'Category[]'.
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #notFound>
    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Category not found!</div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

So I'm lost here. Also I'm new to asp.net and angular. Kindly help.

**Edit:**
api response of category list
[image]

api response when getting a single category by id
[image]

Comment: can you also add the screenshot of API response from browser's network tab.

Comment: What is the return type of  this.categoryService.getCategoryById?

Comment: What others said: would be nice to see api response. Also FYI you defined `Category` as an object, not array. Object has properties (like your id, name, urlHandle) and array has elements, which can be objects (of type Category, for example). So yeah, lets see what api returns.

Comment: As requested I have added the screenshot and thanks for responding!

Comment: It's working now. A tinny mistake in my categoryServices,  `getCategoryById(id:string): Observable<Category[]>{}`  **to**   `getCategoryById(id:string): Observable<Category>{`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if your API return a single json or an Array. It's possible your API return an array with an uniq element
Cast the response

```
this.categoryService.getCategoryById(this.id)
          .subscribe({
            next:((response:Category[]))=>{ //<--"cast" the response
              //only to check if is an array or a single object
              console.log(response) 

              //if return an array with an unique element
              this.category=response[0]; 
            }
          });
```

See that I write `response:Category[]`. Angular don't know what it's the response (really Angular transpile to javaScript, so it's not important for it). When you write `response:Category[]` really not "transform" the response, only **help** to TypeScript to transpile to javascript

**Update**: It's looks like your API return an array with **all** the categories???

You can use some like:

```
this.categoryService.getCategoryById(this.id)
          .subscribe({
            next:((response:Category[]))=>{ 
              this.category=response.find((x:Category)=>x.id==this.id)||
                                                             {} as Category; 
            }
          });
```

But really it's very "ineffective". Perhaf you want create your service like

```
categories!:Category[]
getAllCategories()
{
    if (!this.categories)
      return this.httpClient.get("your-url").pipe(
          tap((response:Category[])=>this.categories=response))

    return of(this.categories) //<--return an observable with
                                    the array
}
getCategorieID(int id)
{
   return this.getAllCategories().pipe(
      map((response:Category[])=>
         response.find((x:Category)=>x.id==id) || {} as Category)
   )
}

//when you want to "reset" the "caché"
resetCategorie()
{
    this.categories=null
}
```

About the code

1. the rxjs operator `of` return an observable with the value of the
   argument
2. the rxjs operator `tap` execute an action when subscribe without
   change the response

Comment: When I checked the console, I got this 
`{
    "id": "ab7355c3-4252-4d95-54cd-08dbbcf9549e",
    "name": "HTML",
    "urlHandle": "html-blogs"
}`

Comment: you're update your question with a response of an array of all Categories, but your comment return an unique object. I update the answer if you received an array of categories, but if you only return an object (see that it's not the same you received `[0]:{id:..,name...}`, that only  `{id:...,name:...}`. (It's the diference between an array with an unique element or an object). If really you only get an object you shoul write some like `next:((response:Category))=>{ this.category=response}`

Comment: yea I got only the object when running the app with the first answer you gave
and now I tried this `next:((response:Category))=>{ this.category=response}` . But it's showing an error saying `No overload matches this call`